# Find the regular expression itself within the string and replace it

Tags: php, regex

I have been presented with a situation where I need to replace part of a string with a value found by a regex but use the regex as the base for the end result.

Caveat: This is to sort out a larger canonicalisation issue on a website.

We have a custom CMS and it will respond to URL's via a regular expression:

eg:

```
Request URI: /mysection/mykey/PageName.htm
Page Match:  /mysection/([^/]+)/pagename.htm
```

If someone requests /mysection/mykey/PageName.htm, although this will work, it's not the correct page, the correct page is /mysection/mykey/pagename.htm in this case.

If I do a case insensitive match initially I can find out if the person linked to the page right or not.  If they didn't, we don't show a 404, what we want to do is generate rel="canonical" in the  section to tell google which page is the correct one and that this is effectively a duplicate.

The correct URL for the page would be:

```
/mysection/mykey/pagename.htm
```

So, what I need to do is superimpose the "mykey" part from Request URI into the Page Match string but getting the page match string's version as a sum of it as the result.

I've been looking at preg_replace but as there can be multiple replacements, you can't give it the required 2nd parameter.

Here's some code i've written to get to where I am now:

```
// $page['uri'] is the regex to match
// $URL is the requested URL at the web server.

// NB: it is not important to worry about if we have found a valid or invalid URL
// at this stage as that has already been processed prior to this point.

if (preg_match("|". $page['uri'] ."|", $URL)) {
    // we get here if the URLs match correctly and case sensitively.
    echo "Matches" . PHP_EOL;
} else {
    // we get here if the URLs don't case sensitively match
    echo "Doesn't match" . PHP_EOL;
}
```

It's in the doesn't match section i'm having trouble as this is where I have to build the rel= "canonical" url which should be the $page['uri'] version with the ([^/]+) replaced with whatever that section of $URI contained.

Comment: Backreferences. Capture parts of the match in brackets, so you can same them as variables.

Comment: I don't think I'm seeing the big picture here. You could simply create a new string by concatenating `/startpath/`, the variable, and `/in/something`, right?

Comment: Aren't you just looking for `preg_replace`?

Comment: backreferences would probably be appropriate but as non-techs are building the URLs that get responded to I can see bigger problems creeping in.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `i` modifier for case in sensitive regular expressions:
http://www.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php

Comment: I've drastically rewritten the question to make it clearer what the problem is.

Comment: You should add some more examples to the question.

Answer (score 0):

It should be a three-step procedure:

1. From your regex, extract the match (here `mykey`)
2. Take a modified version of your regex, but treat it as a simple string: `/mysection/XXXXXXXXXX/pagename.htm`
3. Replace XXXXXXXXXX (or any unique identifier you'd like) wit the match, mykey.

Output is `/mysection/mykey/pagename.htm`

Comment: I'd thought of that dda, because of the dynamic environment I need to figure out where the regex is on the fly to create the simplified version.  If I had multiple regex's in the same URL (which will happen) then I could simply change them to AAA, BBB, CCC etc but they'll not form a uniform pattern so I need to discover the regex - almost like tapping the PCRE library at a lower level.